# Angular4 for both backend & frontend

Tags: angular

I'm going to build my website using client/server

Client using angular4 for both back end (Admin Opertions) & front end (UI Site)

The problem is that they are 2 different design templates with many external js libs.

So should I use one project with 2 modules (back end, front end), or using 2 projects?

If both in one project, I cannot separate the js libs (load external js in module or components), I can just load all of them in the index.html (js for both design template)

If I use 2 projects, then the projects cannot use the shared services class (and the service class need to create 2 times in 2 project)

In short,

I want single angular application for front and admin. e.g. localhost:port for front side components, modules and routers. And localhost:port/admin for admin site components, modules and routers.

Please give me the suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "back end". The backend normally refers to the server-side of the application, i.e. your PHP server. I can't figure out what you're asking, nor what your architecture is.

Comment: @JBNizet Probably means a backoffice

Comment: I want single angular application for front and admin. e.g. http://localhost:port for front side components, modules and routers. And http://localhost:port/admin for admin site components, modules and routers.

Answer (score 1):

> So should I use one project with 2 modules (back end, front end), or
>   using 2 projects?

Depends,
You can maintain all the things in single project ,

> If both in one project, I cannot separate the js libs (load external
>   js in module or components),  I can just load all of them in the
>   index.html (js for both design template)

But then you have to dive deep into [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/),
that can help you with external js,

That can create chunks of the modules and will load it when it required ,
So you can divide them into two part such that,
Admin will load only those packages and frontend will load it's own

Answer (score 0):

Angular application can be built using a logical architecture, in your case you should create one project and if I understand it the right way you want to separate two kind of website / or part of your website. If so you could have something like that :

- Admin
- FrontEnd
- Common

Create components, services and classes directories in each directory, then you'll be able to separate every part of your website.

Now if your question is where to start what to use ? i would say install @angular/cli for the shortcut (ng g c / s...). And start with Angular 2 is preferred.

To consolidate your generated js files, ng build --prod will create the bundle for you, then just install it on your php server as it's html/js only.